# How to approach $\sin x+x<0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have reduced a larger problem to the inequality $\sin x+x<0$. From the [function's graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2Bsinx) it seems that the answer is $x<0$.

But of course, looking at the graph is not a formal answer...

How should I approach such an innocent-looking inequality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint:
$$(\sin{x}+x)'=\cos{x}+1\geq0$$ and $\sin0+0=0$.

Solution without derivatives.

After replacing $x$ on $-x$ we need to prove that $\sin{x}+x>0$ for all $x>0$.

Indeed, for $0<x<\pi$ it's true because $$\sin{x}+x>x>0,$$
but for $x\geq\pi$ it's true becase
$$\sin{x}+x\geq-1+\pi>0.$$

Comment: Thanks. But I haven't yet learned derivatives. Maybe some other approach?

Comment: @Zvika I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

Take $g(x)=\sin x $ ,$f(x)=-x$ and plot both of them . you will see , there is only one solution $x=0$  for $f(x)=g(x)$ .
This mean there is easy  solution for $x+\sin x <0$
 see below figure

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0wmvfmjnjn